# Send array as JSON response after the array is populated by values obtained from mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to send an array of document IDs as JSON response but the array I obtain as the response is empty. How can I make sure the array is populated first by the document `IDs` before it is sent as the response?

```
exports.createItem = async (req,res,next) => {
    let itemsIds = [];
    req.body.forEach( async element => {
        let doc = await Item.findOneAndUpdate({
            type: element.type,
            color: element.color,
            size: element.size
            }, {
            $inc:{stock: element.stock}
            }, {upsert:true, new: true});   
        itemsIds.push(doc._id);
        });
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        itemsIds: itemsIds
    })
}
```

I want to make sure the `res.status(200).json({...})` method runs only after all the doc ids are pushed to the mongo DB. Right now I just get the `itemsIds` as `[ ]` in the response. How I can make sure itemsIds array is populated by the doc ids first before sending the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forEach loop contains a callback function, where we should not use async await, use the for of loop to await for the result, push it into the array and then send the response.

```
exports.createItem = async (req,res,next) => {
    let itemsIds = [];
    for (var element of req.body) {
        let doc = await Item.findOneAndUpdate({
            type: element.type,
            color: element.color,
            size: element.size
            }, {
            $inc:{stock: element.stock}
            }, {upsert:true, new: true});   
        itemsIds.push(doc._id);
    }
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        itemsIds: itemsIds
    })
}
```

Comment: @SagarChilukuri i have updated the answer, please find the answer.

Comment: It works! Thank you. I will mark this answer as the best answer but can you please explain why this method works? Why does it work using for loop instead of forEach() ?

Comment: Once you give a function to forEach, it takes it as a asynchronous call, and its not handled by the main thread any more, so the main thread starts working on the next line, In your case it send the response.